# Embedding a youtube video on WP site

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed

I'm trying to embed a youtube video on a WP site which uses Suarez theme, and the embedded video loads up as a picture, with no interactive elements. I tried to use both original and short links, the embed code, but none seem to work. Any insights on this topic ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show what you entered.  WP automatically parses links to youtube, so you should only have to paste something like this in your "content area" (through the page / post editor): https://youtu.be/1oHWvFrpocY  and it will automatically turn into an embedded video.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I've tried the simple link like you've shown. 
Now my code is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h734_fZmSxc
And the page loads up as : http://zaliejipastataivilnius.lt/video/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use an iframe in the page itself and it worked. Did you try that?

i took a random video then i scrolled down to share and use the embed function. I coped all the code.

Then i went to pages in the wordpress and used my front page for this. Then i went to text in the standaard wordpress editor and pasted the code. hit save and there it was the video

NOTE:
you can make it autoplay when the page loads. and its default to allow full screen.

If you want to make it autoplay paste this behinde your iframe code like this : ?autoplay=1

this src is in you copied iframe tag!

src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-9r7ezjl1us**?autoplay=1**"

Cees

Comment: WP doesn't need iframes for embedding.

Comment: I did try the iframe embedding. Ended up the same.

Comment: When i look at the HTML i makes it an Iframe. but when i paste the link in my browser it simply plays can you try it with a different theme? it does not matter that i look ugly just for a test.

Comment: Or the plugin you use to animate it in?

Comment: I tried it on my other website with a different theme, it seemed to work.

Comment: WordPress Media Uploader allows users to upload images, documents, videos and audios creating a return reference link of the selected media files directly on the post. https://www.wpblog.com/embed-wordpress-videos-audios-images/